# How to get Categories from product id in single page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to retrieve Related Categories from product id.
Suppose I have categories like bellow.

```
iPhone (Parent Category)
  -iPhone 3 (sub)
  -iPhone 4 (sub)
  -iPhone 5 (sub)
  -iPhone 6 (sub)
```

if a Product : iPhone 4 Charger. (in iPhone 4 sub category)

How can I retrieve all above categories by the product id (iPhone 4 Charger)
as a list?

I think Step may be == (get product id) --> (get category) --> (get parent category) --> (get category list of this parent category)

I am trying below code

```
<?php 
$parent = get_category_parents( $cat, true, ' &raquo; ' ); 
echo $product->get_categories( ', ', '<span>' . _n( 'Category:', 'Categories:', sizeof( get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' ) ), 'woocommerce' ) . ' ', '.</span>' ); 
?>
```

Comment: is this what you want ??
http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/31942/category-template-to-show-different-categories-based-on-parent

Comment: are you using woocommerce?? whats the product??

Answer (score 1):

if you are using woocommerce please try this:

```
<?php 
$term_list = wp_get_post_terms($id_product,'product_cat',array('fields'=>'ids'));
$cat_id = (int)$term_list[0];
echo get_term_link ($cat_id, 'product_cat');

?>
```

Comment: @RupomKhondaker: check this link.
http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/163372/how-to-get-woocommerce-product-category-link-by-id